# AMP version of e-commerce without plugin

Tags: php, html

I have two product pages of an ecommerce website: one made with Woocommerce (in WordPress) and one I coded my self in AMP.

[Here](https://www.construction.belram.be/product/nti-audio-xl2-sound-level-meter/) is the WordPress page, and [here](https://amp.belram.be/products/product-config-basic.html) is the AMP page. Not taking into account that the two pages are on two different subdomains, how would I redirect mobile users to the AMP version of the page ?

A similar question was asked, but it only specified how to do it for simple pages, not product pages.

Does anyone know how to that?

Comment: you put some JS code that detect device and screen properties and does the redirect. There is no other way that will scale, but of course it will have a bad UX as you will need to have two http requests instead of one

Comment: Isn't it possible to use a function in functions.php as others have done for pages with if ( is_single() ) ? I'm referring for example to that post: [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/implementing-amp-without-amp-plugin/)

Comment: not sure how that link is relevant to redirection. Anyway, proper detection of device type should be done on browser side. Anything done server side will fail when caching is used